How to show android native view in MAUI
I created the layout in Platforms/Android/Resources/layout/activity_crop_image.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView
        android:id="@+id/cropImageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Then i tried to get this view using this example:
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Com.Canhub.Cropper;

namespace Android.Image.Cropper
{
    public class Instance
    {
        CropImageView cropImageView;

        void CropImage()
        {
            Context context = App.Application.Context;
            Activity? activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;

            if (activity != null) throw new Exception("Activity is null");


            // Null here
            cropImageView = (CropImageView)activity.FindViewById(activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("cropImageView", "id", activity.PackageName));
            Console.WriteLine($"[Image Cropper] {cropImageView}");
        }
    }
}

Why the view is always nulls?

Can you tell me what the purpose of this code is, besides there is only one activity in MAUI, I tested your code, and when I called the SetContentView method of the activity, everything worked fine, and solved the problem you mentioned.

You can't, because you need to instanciate the view in the AndroidManifest, i didnt find any solution to make a android native view using only c#, i need to create any .aar file instead.

Can you tell me how you initialize in AndroidManifest？
